# Условия поиска регулярного выражения java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Дана url ссылка допустим https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8# нужно убрать все цифровые символы, и чтобы вывод ссылки был после первого знака `?` и разделяться параметрами `=` или `-`, вывод ссылки должен быть `sourceid chrome instant ion espv ie UTF`. Xочу решить через регулярные выражения, пока что смог только убрать все символы.

```
String url = "https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8# ";

String regexp1 =  "([?\\.\\&\\:\\;\\/\\=\\-\\#]+)";

// используем Паттерн, компилируем регулярное выражение
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regexp1);

// делаем матчер по созданному паттерну и кидаем в конструктор наш URL.
Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(url);

String output = matcher1.replaceAll(" ");
System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не извращаться регулярками, то можно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13592567/3212712):

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> splitQuery(URL url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
  final Map<String, List<String>> query_pairs = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
  final String[] pairs = url.getQuery().split("&");
  for (String pair : pairs) {
    final int idx = pair.indexOf("=");
    final String key = idx > 0 ? URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), "UTF-8") : pair;
    if (!query_pairs.containsKey(key)) {
      query_pairs.put(key, new LinkedList<String>());
    }
    final String value = idx > 0 && pair.length() > idx + 1 ? URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), "UTF-8") : null;
    query_pairs.get(key).add(value);
  }
  return query_pairs;
}
```

Метод вернёт мапу с параметрами и значениями оных. Из неё уже можно отбросить все значения-числа.

По ссылке есть и другие решения разной степени простоты.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так:

```
String url = "https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourc23eid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\w]+=([\\w-]+)&?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
while (matcher.find())
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

Вывод будет следующий:

> chrome-instant
>   1
>   2
>   UTF-8